# What is the difference between sound drivers in Ubuntu 10 and newer versions?

Tags: sound, 10.10, 14.04, realtek

I am trying to jump from XP and would like to use Ubuntu as it has everything I require.

The problem I am having is that I cannot get the sound to work. I have installed older versions 10.10 and the sound works perfectly, but if I install a newer version the sound doesn't work.

Ubuntu 14.04 is recognising the card (Realtek ALC260) and installing the drivers but in the sound app I only get digital audio and headphones options listed (and the headphones option is constantly flashing).
There is no analog option (there was when I installed 10.10)

I have tried all the mods I can find to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
e.g. snd-hda-intel model=****

But I only get a flashing headphone option and no analog option to select as output.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: anybody any ideas?

Comment: "pavucontrol" is a piece of software that has loads of options for sound (more than the default has). Might be worth a try :)

Comment: Hi Rinzwind thanks for the reply. Tried "pavucontrol" still no joy. Still cannot select audio output via the built in speakers, I can only select headphones - when I plug in headphones they do not work either. I also tried Mint and I cannot select the speakers output in that either.